# I want to Weekly sum for each ID group but a week being here a full week from Sunday to Thursday

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

** I have Input data frame  **

| ID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-03 | 100 |
| A | 2021-08-04 | 100 |
| A | 2021-08-06 | 20 |
| A | 2021-08-07 | 100 |
| A | 2021-08-09 | 300 |
| A | 2021-08-11 | 100 |
| A | 2021-08-12 | 100 |
| A | 2021-08-13 | 10 |
| A | 2021-08-23 | 10 |
| A | 2021-08-24 | 10 |
| A | 2021-08-26 | 10 |
| A | 2021-08-28 | 10 |

desired Output data frame

| ID | Date | Amount | OneWeekAmount | TwoWeekAmount | ThreeWeekAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-03 | 100 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| A | 2021-08-04 | 100 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| A | 2021-08-06 | 20 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| A | 2021-08-07 | 100 | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| A | 2021-08-09 | 300 | 500 | 700 | 700 |
| A | 2021-08-11 | 100 | 500 | 700 | 700 |
| A | 2021-08-12 | 100 | 500 | 700 | 700 |
| A | 2021-08-13 | 10 | 500 | 700 | 700 |
| A | 2021-08-23 | 10 | 30 | 30 | 530 |
| A | 2021-08-24 | 10 | 30 | 30 | 530 |
| A | 2021-08-26 | 10 | 30 | 30 | 530 |
| A | 2021-08-28 | 10 | 30 | 30 | 530 |

**Note** : **Here  week being here a full week from Sunday to Thursday.**
I need Weekly sum in OneWeekAmount for each group i.e.. I have  summed amount for date because 2021-08-03 and 2021-08-04 the days are Tuesday and Wednesday respectively, and excluded for 2021-08-06 , 2021-08-07 days are Friday and Saturday respectively.
TwoWeekAmount = OneWeekAmount + Previous Week Amount
ThreeWeekAmount = Present week + previous two week sum

Please help in get this output.
**Thanking you in advanced.**

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['ID', df['date'].dt.week])['amount'].sum()
```

Comment: you should transforme your date colone to datetime use this : df['date']=pd.to_datetime(dd, format="%d-%m-%Y")

Comment: Edit your answer to add additional information. Don't use a comment.